# Google Sheets - Loot Council. How to generate a list of items each character has priority on?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: world of warcraft loot council]

I've been manually making lists of all the items each character has priority on for easy comparison of who has how much.

The sheet has been updated and redoing the work is something I'm not happy about.

I would be supremely grateful if someone could instruct me on how to generate a table with the character names with a list of each item they have received priority on.

This would involve checking for their names, referring to the name of the item in the first column. I can't quite work it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured all of this out by now but I just discovered the power of thatsmybis.com combined with the addon Gargul. They have a disc group that is very active for feedback & help. TMB can be exported with everything you need into excel and you have a full list of everything. Hope this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).